# The best way of coding web system in term of performance

Tags: c++, php, performance, web-servers

So far I've been using IPB and my custom scripts all coded in PHP but I am really disappointed of the long term performance of it.

I would like to move to native coding, the learning time to put into doesn't matter at all.
Ive found CppCMS and it seems to be the exact solution i was searching for.

I would like to know from anyone who has chosen this way, what have you done?
Is CppCMS the best one in term of performance?

If yes, with what webserver should I run it with and any special configuration?

I am really searching for the best way to go in term of performance (learning time and coding time does not matter).

Comment: Doesn't CppCMS have a dedicated website ? Don't they have these informations there ? (requirements, installation instructions etc.)

Comment: They do, they actually explain how to set it up on several different webservers, which in turn doesn't answer my question "which way is the best in term of performance".

Comment: My question is directed to people who met the same situation as mine.

Comment: @user1588293 - Just because CppCMS is in C++ doesn't mean it will have the best performance (or at least, not proportionate to the costs of learning and implementing it for anything other than projects that will be required to scale). I'm not discounting the benefits of CppCMS, just saying it may be overkill. If you're a beginner/intermediate programmer and are used to working in PHP, I would first look at PHP frameworks like Symfony2, Laravel, etc just to familiarize yourself with modern web development practices *away* from IPB extensions.

Comment: @Anonymous you're not going to get good performance by moving from a set of PHP scripts to a different set of PHP scripts. He says the learning time is not a factor here anyway.

Comment: what do you mean by "long term performance"?

Comment: @gbjbaanb - Strongly disagree. So 'PHP scripts' won't run faster if you implement caching (just as an example) (like many frameworks do...)? I don't know the ins-and-outs of IPB development, but I can see the overhead of IPB killing performance compared to a modern, performant framework.

Comment: @Anonymous - so can't he cache his IPB/PHP scripts too? That wasn't his question anyway - he said he wanted to "move to native coding", that question has nothing to do with PHP bytecode caching.

Answer (score 3):

Performance problems with web applications rarely are caused by the choice of language. More typically they are caused in faulty architecture design.

While PHP is [the slowest performing](http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/) in web app development, and it's a [mess of a language](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/), there are plenty [examples](http://highscalability.com/blog/2012/9/26/wordpresscom-serves-70000-reqsec-and-over-15-gbitsec-of-traf.html) of very high traffic web sites using PHP.

You also say that:

> learning time and coding time does not matter.

It does. If you have fixed deadline, each hour you have to spend on mundane coding is each hour less spent on architecture design, testing etc.

Comment: The keyword "if". I don't have a fixed deadline.

Comment: @user1588293: you always do, even if it's not explicit.

Answer (score 1):

CppCMS is a good solution, but another one to look at is Microsoft's [Casablanca](http://casablanca.codeplex.com/) which is designed for very efficient (and fast) performance for the cloud. Note that is offers a lot of web-style tooling but it is not a "website framework" for easily writing a website, more about writing webservices and REST APIs.